# Does Spock have any human physical characteristics that pure Vulcans don't have?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, spock

Throughout Star Trek, Spock is referred to as having many Vulcan characteristics such as his pointed ears and inner eyelids. He is also stated to be half-human. Are there any human physical characteristics mentioned on-screen that he possesses that pure Vulcans don't?

Also, I am aware he did have occasional struggles with suppressing emotions, but, other Vulcans  (namely pure Vulans), such as T'Pol and Tuvok have similar issues.

Comment: I'd maybe go with a title like "Which of Spock's traits come from his half-human side?" or something like that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The only non-mental evidence of his human heritage mentioned in the ["Physiology" section of his Memory Alpha article](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock#Physiology) is a scene from the episode ["Journey to Babel"](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/44.htm), in which his father Sarek needs a blood transfusion and there is the following discussion:

> SAREK: My blood type is T-negative. Somewhat rare, even for a Vulcan.
>
> MCCOY: Yes, I'd say that's rare.
>
> SPOCK: My blood is T-negative, Doctor.
>
> CHAPEL: We've run a number of blood tests on Mister Spock. **It isn't true Vulcan blood either. It has human blood elements in it.**
>
> SPOCK: It should be possible to filter out the human factors.
>
> MCCOY: Even you couldn't give that much blood, Spock. It would kill you.

Comment: Was not expecting a concrete answer, given how the character was created by adding attributes to a human actor. +1.

Comment: Ah, human blood elements, the worst kind!

Comment: @RogueJedi   I imagine Sarek thinking   "eww human cooties!"

Comment: Would his blood become more or less green without the human elements I wonder?  Blue and red would be unlikely to make green blood so maybe there are copper bloods around that look green?

Comment: @TafT +1... I, too, just started to think about such questions.

Comment: When you start to think about it you realise that there is no way humans could reliably reproduce with Vulcans. At best it would be a one-in-a-thousand that he'd be born at all and you'd expect a hundred health issues to besiege him. Human antibodies would attack the Vulcan elements, and the reverse. If the brain used only Vulcan blood cells or only human blood cells, it wouldn't get enough Oxygen to survive. You'd also expect mental problems beyond a little trouble with emotional control, like instinct conflicts. You would need extensive genetic modification to make him viable.

Comment: @PointlessSpike: You're not...thinking scientifically about *ST*?!

Comment: @RogueJedi: *"Terrible, having bad blood like that."*

Comment: @PointlessSpike "extensive genetic modification" -- I remember reading that it took a lot of genetic engineering (maybe not exactly that phrase) for Spock to be conceived.  I have no idea where I read that.  Maybe you have a question here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder- You should see my reactions when watching TV. I'm like Kirk on the bridge of the Enterprise-B.